# NIGHTWATCH JS - How to debug without relaunching a new execution each time

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I did not find what I'm looking for on different sites. 
In fact, when I write my tests with NIGHTWATCH for WEB forms, I have to re-test my entire test each time I want to check something that I have just corrected. 
Is there a way to keep the browser open on a page to restart only a small part ? because it can be very long on forms tests with several pages or tabs.

Thanks,

Comment: I've only been using nightwatch for a short time but I haven't seen anything like what you are describing. The closest thing I think you will get is using the `--testcase` flag to run a single test case.

Comment: Hello tehbeardedone.

Comment: Hello tehbeardedone,
I specify my problem: in the same test, I have to fill several tabs of successive forms and thus to debug a problem on one of the forms, I have to relaunch the url of the site to iron one by one the different tabs until the one who interest me .. because I do not have a way to keep my session open on one of the tabs and just restart the relevant part of code (my global test). I also use UFT for other tests, and we did it with this tool .. I do not know if other people have had the same problem (which may be due to SELENIUM).